# page in jquery dialog box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have dataTable which last column for edit. I have a separate page for edit form. what i want is when edit link is clicked open that page in a jQuery dialog box and submit data.

Comment: Id's cannot repeat on a single page.  It looks like you are potentially creating multiple a tags with the same 'myHref' id.  Not sure if that is your whole issue, but that is an issue.  Unless i'm misreading this.

Comment: @dil i added a workaround for what i think you want. The question is not all clear so let me know if you want something different.

Answer (score 0):

**The correct way to solve this problem**

Assuming that you want a popup or a more specific term `modal` to edit the form, you should not have a separate html view for that but actually make a general form and post data using ajax. Creating a separate page defeats that purpose.

Now assuming that you still want to have a separate page for that. The modal should be like

```
<div class="modal">
    <iframe src="" id="frameSrc">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

where the `src` contains the url of the page that you want to open, i am guessing from the `href`. So here is how you would do that in javascript

```
$(this).on("click", function () {
    var editUri = $this.attr('href');
    document.getElementById('frameSrc').src = editUri;
});
```

The javascript will get the url from href and substitute the `src` in `iframe` tag in modal.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

you can do this without alert and you don't need send href to jquery 
use fadeIn and some style to make it.

```js
$('a#login').click(function(){
 $("#bgstyle").fadeIn('slow');
    $('form').fadeIn('slow');
    
})
```

**[Fiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/M1L4D/bxwtohrs/1/)**
hope this help you

anyway if i wanna do this i prefer to use bootstrap modal.